# Quotient of a topological group a principal bundle?

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-cohomology, principal-bundles

Let $G$ be a topological group and $H\subseteq G$ be a subgroup. Then the projection $p:G\to G/H$ is an $H$-bundle with $H$ acting freely and transitively on the fibres. What conditions do I need to make $p$ a principal bundle?

Comment: is the local triviality a consequence?

Comment: If I understood you correctly: Yes, if $p$ was a principal bundle, then $p$ would be in particular a fibre bundle with fibre $H$.

Comment: You can check the section “Lie group actions on manifolds” in Lee’s book introduction to smooth manifolds, second edition